# "On the tennis court", a prepositional phrase, in this context modifies what?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Althea Gibson was graceful **on the tennis court.**

I learned it modifies the adjective graceful, but I have a doubt. Plz someone explain me clearly why it is so..

Comment: The PP "on the tennis court" doesn't modify "graceful". "Graceful on the tennis court" is not a constituent, not a grammatical unit. The PP is actually a modifier in clause structure, where it modifies the verb phrase "was graceful".

Comment: @BillJ: What is the reasoning behind the practice of saying the modifier modifies only the verb phrase? Why is the subject of the verb excluded? Is that just an artefact of  separating NP from VP on the tree, and needing a branch on which to "hang" the adjunct?

Comment: @Tim Because syntactically it's part of the predicate, i.e. part of the VP.

Comment: @BillJ And that's the case no matter where it appears in the clause structure, even if it's preposed? Adjuncts of place or time or manner are syntactically part of the predicate?

Comment: *Semantically*, I'm inclined to see ***on the tennis court*** as modifying the entire preceding assertion ***Althea Gibson was graceful*** (the implication being that assertion isn't true in all other contexts).

Comment: @Tim Yes: consider "[When I was at school ] I wasn't allowed to watch TV __". Here the bracketed PP is a preposed temporal adjunct in prenuclear position functioning as modifier in the VP.

Comment: @BillJ, wow, you do puzzle me with your analyses that rate *when* a preposition. (N.B.—I’ve interpreted your “PP” to mean prepositional phrase. Is that wrong?) In your example, *when* could be replaced with *because*. Does that mean that *because* is a preposition?

Comment: @BillJ Give answer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Althea Gibson was graceful* [*on the tennis court*].

The locative PP "on the tennis court" doesn't modify "graceful". "Graceful on the tennis court" is not a constituent, not a grammatical unit. The PP is actually an adjunct, a modifier in clause structure, i.e. it modifies the verb phrase "was graceful".

Consider also this example containing a preposed temporal adjunct:

> [*When I was at school*] *I wasn't allowed to watch TV* ___.

Here the bracketed PP is a temporal adjunct in preposed (prenuclear) position. The nucleus of the clause contains a gap '___ ' in the position where the adjunct would normally occur in the non-preposed equivalent. The preposed element is linked to the gap '___' so we can say that it takes on that function, i.e. of modifier in the VP "wasn't allowed to watch TV".